# How can i set up my interstitial and banner ads to one java class instead of having to integrate it in every class

Tags: java, android, admob, banner, interstitial

So each activity I create I have to integrate my ads in the class and I have a number of activities. So I noticed it just keeps increasing the app size. is there a way to integrate all ads in one java class instead of each and every activity having its own class.

Here's an example.

```
public class TradingStyle extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button2;

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mInterstitialAd != null)
        {
            mInterstitialAd.show(TradingStyle.this);
            return;
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trading_style);

        this.button2 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2));
        button2.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(TradingStyle.this);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.show();
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

            InterstitialAd.load(TradingStyle.this,TradingStyle.this.getString(R.string.main_inter), adRequest,
                    new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                            // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                            // an ad is loaded.
                            pd.dismiss();
                            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;

                            mInterstitialAd.show(TradingStyle.this);
                            mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
                                @Override
                                public void onAdClicked() {
                                    // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                    // Called when ad is dismissed.
                                    // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                                    TradingStyle.this.startActivity(new Intent( TradingStyle.this, TradingStyleMenu.class)); //Youll replace this to suit button
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                                    // Called when ad fails to show.
                                    mInterstitialAd = null;

                                    TradingStyle.this.startActivity(new Intent( TradingStyle.this, TradingStyleMenu.class)); //Also replace this
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdImpression() {
                                    // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                    // Called when ad is shown.
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                            // Handle the error
                            pd.dismiss();
                            mInterstitialAd = null;
                            TradingStyle.this.startActivity(new Intent( TradingStyle.this, TradingStyleMenu.class));
                        }
                    });


        });

        //Start Here
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        InterstitialAd.load(this,TradingStyle.this.getString(R.string.main_inter), adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;

                        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
                            @Override
                            public void onAdClicked() {
                                // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when ad is dismissed.
                                // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                                TradingStyle.this.finish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                                // Called when ad fails to show.
                                mInterstitialAd = null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdImpression() {
                                // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when ad is shown.
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.rate) {
            String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trade.earneasily";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }
}
```

l'm looking for a way to integrate all ads in one class.

Comment: by either inheritance or composition, both quite basic concepts in Java development

Comment: ...or delegation...or a utility class.  Just move the bulk the shared logic into a shared location.  As @Stultuske suggests, there are a number of ways of doing this.